# Не могу подключить файлы в Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
<?php

class View {
    const VIEWS_DIR = 'views';
    const VIEW_EXTENSION = 'php';

    protected $headers = [
        '<meta charset="utf-8">',
        true ? '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">' : '',
    ];
    protected $title;
    protected $css = [
        '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
        '/css/common.css'
    ];
    protected $js = [
        '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
        '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        '/js/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js',
        '/js/phone.min.js',
        '/js/common.js'
    ];
    private $app;
    private $viewPath;
    private $output = [];

    function __construct($app) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->viewPath = $this->app->projectRoot.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.self::VIEWS_DIR;
    }

    public function render($viewName, $params = []) {
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) { $$key = $value; }
        ob_start();
        $this->setupHeaders();
        require_once implode('.', [$this->viewPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$viewName, self::VIEW_EXTENSION]);
        $content = ob_get_flush();
        ob_flush();
        return $content;
    }

    private function setupHeaders() {
        $this->output[] = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
        $this->output[] = '<html><head>';
        foreach ($this->headers as $head) { $this->output[] = $head; }
        foreach ($this->css as $css) { $this->output[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css.'">'; }
        foreach ($this->js as $js) { $this->output[] = '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$js.'"></script>'; }
        $this->output[] = '</head>';
        echo implode(PHP_EOL, $this->output);
    }
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * @var $this View
 */
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row form-group field">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">
                        Имя:
                        <span class="error"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите имя" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group field">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">
                        Телефон:
                        <span class="error"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group field">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">
                        E-mail:
                        <span class="error"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="username@sitename.com" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group field">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">
                        Комментарий:
                        <span class="error"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="5" placeholder="Можно написать пару слов..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <span class="error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right form-submit">
                            Отправить
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="thank-you">
                Спасибо!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

А что это за класс View? Если вопрос относится к Yii2, то тут явно чего-то не хватает. По канонам Yii2 для подключения файлов стилей и скриптов, необходимо воспользоваться классом, который расширяет `yii\web\AssetBundle`.

Класс комплекта ресурсов может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class SarAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower';
    public $js = [
        'simple-ajax-requests/dist/sar.js',
    ];
}
```

Чтобы файлы ресурсов были включены на странице, необходимо зарегистрировать этот класс в файле представления:

```
SarAsset::register($this);
```

Более подробно про комплекты ресурсов https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-structure-assets.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
Проблема была у Windows, Linux все работает